# azure mobile services .net backend add scope to facebook login

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to get more user data from facebook login using azure mobile serivces .net backend.

I stumble upon this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/12/12/expanded-login-scopes-in-azure-mobile-services.aspx)

it would seemed that the javascript ams have this ability. I try to mimic this in the .net preview and add to the configuration in the portal the key MS_FacebookScope but nothing happen.

Is there are way how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have just announced the availability of this feature for the .NET backend.

This is the announcement - http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/02/custom-login-scopes-single-sign-on-new-asp-net-web-api-updates-to-the-azure-mobile-services-net-backend/

Take a look at Custom Scopes for Social Authentication Providers - I believe that this is the information that you are looking for.